# goodfit to high count data - Inf & NaN

Tags: r, poisson, goodness-of-fit

I have high count data and apply `goodfit` from the `vcd` package, like so:

```
fishdata <- read.csv("http://dl.dropbox.com/s/4w0utkqdhqribl4/fishdata.csv", header=T)
attach(fishdata)
require(vcd)
dat <- fishdata$inlandfao
gf <- goodfit(dat, method="ML")
gf2 <- goodfit(dat, method="MinChisq")
    > summary(gf); summary(gf2)

         Goodness-of-fit test for poisson distribution

                 X^2 df P(> X^2)
Likelihood Ratio Inf 60        0

         Goodness-of-fit test for poisson distribution

        X^2      df P(> X^2)
Pearson NaN 1218936      NaN
Warning message:
In summary.goodfit(gf2) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

So clearly my data don't follow a Poisson distribution. I just want to know why I obtain this output (the Inf, 0 p-value & NaN). I write this here rather than Cross Validated because I think it's more of a computational issue than a statistical one.

There are no 0's in my data either so that's not the problem. I assume it's because of the very high counts.

Comment: For `gf`, the X^2 value is so high, that it's practically infinitely high. The higher the X^2 value, the lower the P. I don't know how MinChisq works, but 1218936 degrees of freedom smells fishy. Perhaps because there's so many DF, the X^2 value can't be computed accurately (hence the warning)?

Comment: However, I would recommend you reconsider your analysis. Plot the data first and decide what model you want to fit depending on the problem you want to answer. Try `library(reshape2);
library(ggplot2);
fd <- melt(fishdata, id.vars = "year");
head(fd);

ggplot(fd, aes(x = year, y = value)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ variable)`